# Method List in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've recently started using the Visual Studio Code editor.  I'm really loving it, but there's one critical feature (for me) that I haven't been able to find.  Is there a method list, similar to the Navigator in NetBeans or Member dropdown in Visual Studio?

Comment: See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved

Comment: This missing feature is being tracked at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5605

Comment: Released! https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_24#_outline-view

Comment: I don't have an answer, and couldn't get anything suggested on this page to work, so I use the free version of CodeLobster, and have for years. It's very easy to learn, and has plenty of framework intellisense, too. It also shows functions and methods for pages with different scripting languages, too, ie PHP and Javascript.

Comment: Unfortunately, neither Outline in the sidebar nor the `Ctrl+Shift+O+:` seem to be able to filter the symbols by their visibilities(e.g., only the `public` ones). There are also issues([issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/103305) & [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/113238) for instance) on vscode's GitHub, but they are both closed because _it is said that_ they are duplicates, while I couldn't find the main issue. Could anyone find the main issue so that I can support it?

Answer (score 442):

Yes, there is the `workbench.action.gotoSymbol` command. On Windows and Linux it's set to <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> by default, on Mac it's <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.

If this command isn't available for the file types you are working with then you should take a look at the [VSCode extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode/Languages?sortBy=Downloads). Not all languages support this feature.

Comment: Hmm, not the behavior I was hoping for.  I tried a couple of file types:  In a C++ file, it says "Unfortunately we have no symbol information for the file" and in Python it says "There was an error in the Python extension".

Comment: Well, dang, looks like I'm out of luck.  I tried a different Python extension, now I'm getting the "no symbol information" error.  :(  Thanks for the info, though.

Comment: This is [symbols for PHP](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=linyang95.php-symbols).

Comment: Works great in javascript, shortcut can be different when using other shortcut keymaps

Comment: Adding to this one, if you press `:` after `Ctrl+ Shift + O`, the results will be group by type, which will list all the functions in one sublist.

Comment: For macOS users its `Cmd + Shift + O`

Comment: is there a way to do a global lookup, not just in the file i'm in?

Comment: `Ctrl + T` does a global symbol lookup

Comment: Is there a way to only list the public methods?

Comment: Vscode 活动文本编辑器不提供符号信息

Answer (score 323):

**Update**: As stated in the comments by @jeff-xiao this extension is Deprecated and it's now a [built in feature of Visual Studio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_25#_outline-view).  It should be available at the bottom of file explorer as "Outline" view.

Previous text:
There is now an Extension that supports this.  [Code Outline](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=patrys.vscode-code-outline) creates a panel in the "Explorer" section and for JavaScript, will list variables and functions in a file.  I've been using this for a while now and it scratches the itch I had.  Other commenters have mentioned it supports Python and PHP well.

It still seems to be in development but I haven't had any issues.  Development version available [on GitHub](https://github.com/patrys/vscode-code-outline).  If you're the author reading this - thanks!

This is how it looks:
[image: Code Outline plugin for VSCode]

If Code Outline is not visible, you can show it by:
[image]

Comment: Good call, works well with JavaScript & no hunting for hidden keyboard shortcuts, nice.

Comment: The extension is deprecated: DEPRECATED. Please use the [Outline view](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_24#_outline-view) that comes with Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Am I correct that doesn't support viewing all the methods of a class in Python?

Comment: I guess sometimes outline view doesn't show anything for python files.

Comment: Is there such an option for C++?

Comment: The new Outline view does not work for me.... even Java classes read `No symbols found in ClassNameHere.java` any idea how to fix that?

Comment: @dko You may need to edit the file first. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66921231/10792235

Comment: By the way, if you don't like the Outline dropdown being at the bottom, you can drag it to the icon bar at the left for full access.

Comment: Is there a way to show only the name of the methods when using this shortcut? So in your screenshot it will list only the names with the purple icon and not the rest referring to the params of each method

Answer (score 169):

Invoke Code's `Go to symbol` command:

- macOS: <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> (the letter `o`, not zero)
- Windows/Linux: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>

Typing a colon (<kbd>:</kbd>) after invoking `Go to symbol` will group symbols by type (classes, interfaces, methods, properties, variables). Then just scroll to the `methods` section.

Comment: Confirmed it also works on PHP too, but please notice I have PHP intellisense plugin installed. I don't know if it makes any difference.

Comment: There must be an easy way to just see the methods.  It's kind of a pain to scroll through the list of a bunch of other stuff to find the methods section.  Someone should make a plug-in to do that if it isn't possible otherwise.

Comment: type @ instead of : for Go functions listing

Comment: If not working for PHP then make sure you have 'PHP Symbols' plugin and will work for sure.

Answer (score 89):

In 2020 version of VSCode
<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

- <kbd>#</kbd> - Find symbol across files
- <kbd>@</kbd> - Find symbol within file
- <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> - Group symbols within a file

[image: Symbols in a file]
[image: VS Code v1.44.0]

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty handy!

Comment: This is not I initially looking, but it is much better

Answer (score 36):

In [VSCode 1.24](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_24#_outline-view) you can do that.

Right click on `EXPLORER` on the side bar and checked `Outline`.

Comment: I cannot explore methods of a js class using outline!

Comment: works fine for Java! I'm using vscode 2020 updated version

Comment: But that's an outline which shows way more than just the methods, like the convenient dropdownbox right above your edit window. Without having to resort to shortcuts and extra typing to get what I want. `edit` Hmm.. Breadcrums is actually what is more in line with it, if you're already in a routine, you can just click on the breadcrum and it'll popup a dropdownbox..

Comment: This **OUTLINE** tab shows Java methods only after installing Ms Extension Pack for Java. It doesn't list anything for Kotlin files, I guess I need to get an extension for every single thing... save me Jebus!

Answer (score 25):

There is a new release that can do that! 
Check here [the latest release notes regarding code outline](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_24#_outline-view)

[image]

Comment: Nothing is shown until the proper extensions are installed. I got the Ms Extension Pack for Java and it lists Java methods now, but no Kotlin methods. Installing an extension for every little thing is simply idiotic.

Answer (score 20):

**UPDATE:** The extension features are now built-in and the extension itself is now deprecated

I have found this extention: [Code Outline](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=patrys.vscode-code-outline/). 
This is how it looks like:

---

[image: This is how it looks like]

---

I believe that is what you have been looking for.

Comment: This extension no longer exists. I think it has been unpublished because the feature is now built into VSCode.

Answer (score 14):

There's no such feature today,
the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> == <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> @ doesn't work for all languages.

As a last resort you can use the search panel - although it is not so fast an easy to use as you'd like - you can enter this regex in the search panel to find all functions:

```
function\s([_A-Za-z0-9]+)\s*\(
```

Comment: That won't work as we can write `name = function`, `name: function` (inside object) and arrow function in JavaScript

Answer (score 14):

For PHP users :)

1. Make sure you have '***PHP Symbol***' plugin then you can get all methods and class in '***OUTLINE***' Sidebar's Bottom.
2. Press <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> in "macOS" or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> while using "Windows"

> OUTLINE:
>   [image]
>
> @Symbol:
>   [image]

Comment: This works perfectly.

Answer (score 13):

For **python** in **Explorer View**, click on **OUTLINE** as below:

[image]

Comment: For an eclipse like experience you can also drag that tab over the right hand gutter!

Answer (score 10):

Watch this link: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_40#_type-filters-for-outline-and-breadcrumbs

Explorer -> OUTLINE, you can choose what you want to show (only methods and functions in your case) and the result is similar to Netbeans:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Visual Studio Code market place has a very nice extension named [Go To Method](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=trixnz.go-to-method) for navigating *only* methods in a code file.

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and type the `install extensions` and press enter

[image]

Now type `Add to method` in search box of extensions market place and press enter.

[image]

Click <kbd>install</kbd> to install the extension.

Last step is to bind a keyboard shortcut to the command `workbench.action.gotoMethod` to make it a real productivity thing for a developer.

Answer (score 6):

It is an extra part to the answer to this question here but I thought it might be useful. As many people mentioned, Visual Studio Code has the [OUTLINE](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_24#_outline-view) part which provides the ability to browse to different function and show them on the side.

I also wanted to add that if you check the follow cursor mark, it highlights that function name in the OUTLINE view, which is very helpful in browsing and seeing which function you are in.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[Open symbol by name](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_open-symbol-by-name) :
 <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
 might be what you are looking for. Works perfectly with my TypeScript project.

Answer (score 4):

```
ctrl+shift+o // This should work for javascript files by default
```

For PHP install the extension [PHP SYMBOLS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=linyang95.php-symbols)

FOR PYTHON install the extension [PYTHON](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python)

On Reload, this will work fine

Comment: You could also do `Ctrl+P` and type `@` - this lists all functions/symbols in the file. And when typing `@function_name` does a fuzzy string search on the symbols.

Comment: yes nice suggestion.. but you know it requires two steps, where as ctrl+shift+o is single step.  :)

Answer (score 4):

in-built code OUTLINE available now with VS code
[image: Code Outline]

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin called [show functions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qrti.funclist) which lists all the function definitions in a file. It also allows you to sort the function so can search them easily.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> (<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd> for Mac) - opens for me all methods and members in PHP class.

Comment: Didn't work, are you sure you are not using any extension?

Comment: This only worked for me in `Intellij Idea`, but not for `Visual Studio Code`.

Answer (score 1):

For find method in all files you can press `CTRL + P` and then start search with `#`

example : `#signin`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you still can't figure where outline is then Click View->Open View -> outline

Or in command palette (Ctrl + P) the type: **view Outline**

Your outline will now be visible.

Comment: How is this different from the existing Answers?

Comment: @ryanwebjackson There was no outline window on my VS (don't know how it disappeared :) ) and I was struggling on getting it back.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `Show Functions` plugin.
It can list functions, symbols, bookmarks by configurable regular expressions. Regular expressions are a real saver, expecially when you're not using a mainstream language and when CodeOutline doesn't do the job.
It's ugly to see a split window with these functions (CodeOutline seems to be better integrated) but at least there's something to use

Answer (score 0):

If you are using typescript you can use this extension "**Code navigator for typescript**".

I have been trying it and found it useful to list my typescript class methods.

Answer (score 0):

Go to vs-code preferences, search for:
Breadcrumbs: Symbol Sort Order:

And choose "By type."

Answer (score -1):

So, read all the threads, checked all the methods described and i can say: everything is working but have one big limit: there is no possibility to go to parent methods. This is critical point for me and PHP Intelephense plugin doesn't have such feature