# How search for method in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there's any functionality simillar to CTRL+R of sublime in VSCode?

[image: Sublime search method functionality]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Method List in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36154283/method-list-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Within the current file or within the open project/folder?

Comment: Would that be the sort of functionality provided by https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=trixnz.go-to-method or https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kbysiec.vscode-search-everywhere ?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Go to Symbol `workbench.action.gotoSymbol` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> on a Mac).

You can reassign it to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

You can also group them by typing colon `@:`.

Comment: In case it helps anyone reading this, press Ctrl+P for "quick open", then you can use @ or @:

The latter is handy to see all the symbols in the file grouped by classes, constants, fields, methods... (for C# in my case)

Comment: how would I do a global search for a method in all my files?

Comment: For Ruby, you need this extension to make `gotoSymbol` work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65607196/1852005

Comment: Getting message "No editor Symbols", not worked this solution for me. Thanks

Answer (score 98):

To search a method name across all files you can use `CTRL + P` and then start search with `#` (to get directly here use `CTR+T`)

For example: `#register`

[image]

Comment: This is handy although it should be noted that it searches across files, not just the current file. Also, Ctrl+T does the same thing.

Comment: use @ instead to look for fields/methods within a file.
@register
@myMethod()

Comment: Very useful. I use Ctrl + R to search within the file to get the same behavior as Sublime Text.

Comment: Not worked for me, getting message "No matching workspace symbols" while I have function in opened file.

Answer (score 25):

I found multiple options to search function/definition.

According to your convenience, you can choose one of the below options :

1. Best shortcut: `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`O` and type your function name.
2. Press `Ctrl+P` for "quick open", then you can use `@` or `@:` The latter is handy to see all the symbols in the file grouped by classes, constants, fields, methods
3. Press `Ctrl+T` to searches across files, not just the current file.

Thanks, @kevinvictor and @alex

Comment: Getting message "No editor Symbols", not worked this solution for me. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

The answer is to use Ctrl + T and start typing a method name.

(It searches for the method name in multiple files. You can use Ctrl + F to do the search in the current file.)

More detailed answer -

There are several ways to do a search in VS Code. One global way to do a search is to use Ctrl + P.

When you first click on Ctrl + P (Go to File), it shows the recently opened files.

1. Then when you start typing in the search box not beginning with a special character like # or @, it will search for files.
2. But when you start typing in the search box beginning with a special character like # or @, it will search for other things.

   Ctrl + P + # - show all symbols including methods in all files
   (same as shortcut: Ctrl + T)

   Ctrl + P + @ - go to symbol (same as shortcut: Ctrl + Shift + O)

Answer (score 4):

Having same issue in Visual Studio editor. I simply install PHP IntelliSense extension.

You can find this extension in ctrl + shift + x search **IntelliSense** and install it. And then type ctrl + shift + o so you can see all method and function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check for multiple uses of a function in VSCode another quick way to do this is

By using CTRL+CLICK (Windows) or CMD+CLICK (Mac) on the function name and then you would see a column on the right which would tell you all the other places in the file system that function has been used.

[image: What lookup looks like]