# How to see and navigate through functions list in rails, using vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have visual studio code.

How do I see and navigate through the functions list in **rails**?

I don't see any methods in the "outline view". Also, when I use `ctrl + shift + o`, I get the following message: "the active text editor does not provide symbol information".

Is there an extension that need to be installed? Or is it something in settings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See discussion thread about possible options here: https://github.com/rubyide/vscode-ruby/issues/40

At the time of writing, I think the best option is to add the ruby-symbols extension here:
https://github.com/MiguelSavignano/vscode-ruby-symbols

[image: ruby-symbols-extension]

Note also that for Windows, it's Ctrl + Shift + O.

And for Macs, it's Cmd + Shift + O.