# VSCode-Python Outline view for Python in VSCode on Linux not working

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Running VSCode on Ubuntu 16.04.3
VSCode Version: 1.26.1
Microsoft Python Extension: 2018.7.1

When I view a python file the outline view shows No symbols found in document. Same file in VSCode on Windows shows all the symbols

Any help?

Comment: If this is after immediately opening a file and using the new language server then it's a known issue. Otherwise open an issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues with sample code that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: No the file is open for a while. It does not seem specific to a given python file either.

Comment: Open, but have you edited it? But as I said, you can open an issue if you would like us to look into it.

Comment: Ok, based on your comment I edited the file. As soon as I added a space it loaded the symbols. Is that the expected behavior? The file has been open in my editor for days. On edit the symbols load in couple of seconds. I will go ahead and open an issue

Comment: Bug https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2334

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: Wow, it's that simple - press Space, then Ctrl+Z! (now seriously: I'm also waiting for them fixing it...)

Answer (score 1):

Summing up answers found in the comments...

Opened Python files that have not yet been edited will not show anything in the Outline View (message is "No symbols found in document 'xyz'"). Once the file has been edited and saved, the Outline View will populate correctly.

This is a known issue being tracked at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/2334.